# Check if multiple secrets exist in Github Actions

Tags: yaml, github-actions

I want to check that all necessary secrets exist and fail the build if some of them are missing.

In my script I have this step

```
- name: Check if secrets exist
  env:
    secret_key1: ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET_1 }}
    secret_key2: ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET_2 }}
    secret_key3: ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET_3 }}
  if: ${{ env.secret_key1 == '' }} || ${{ env.secret_key2 == '' }} || ${{ env.secret_key3 == '' }}
  run: exit 1
```

but this always exists with status code 1, even if all secrets are present.
I have checked that if I use only one secret it works correctly, e.g.

```
- name: Check if secret exists
  env:
    secret_key: ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET }}
  if: ${{ env.secret_key == '' }}
  run: exit 1
```

Am I using wrong syntax or is the problem somewhere else?

Comment: Did you try using `if: ${{ env.secret_key1 == ''  ||  env.secret_key2 == '' || env.secret_key3 == '' }}` with the whole expression between brackets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition should look like this:

```yaml
- name: Check if secrets exist
  env:
    secret_key1: ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET_1 }}
    secret_key2: ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET_2 }}
    secret_key3: ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET_3 }}
  if: ${{ (env.secret_key1 == '') || (env.secret_key2 == '') || (env.secret_key3 == '') }}
  run: exit 1
```

Also, you can omit the expression syntax (`${{ }}`) because GitHub automatically evaluates the `if` conditional as an expression:

```yaml
- name: Check if secrets exist
  env:
    secret_key1: ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET_1 }}
    secret_key2: ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET_2 }}
    secret_key3: ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET_3 }}
  if: env.secret_key1 == '' || env.secret_key2 == '' || env.secret_key3 == ''
  run: exit 1
```

Screenshot: [click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsD7t.png)

For more information, see [Expressions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions).